# bash script exiting when setting variable to curl output

Tags: bash, function, variables, curl

Trying to create a function to check if there are issues with the SSL on a webpage.In the specific scenario we've setup the expected output for curl https://domain includes:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
```

...we are using grep, as per the line below to to set the SSL_STATUS variable to that line which we will then pump through an if statement. Problem is that it sets the variable and then drops out of the script for no apparent reason:

```
+ https_status
++ curl https://steelrain.eu
++ grep 'SSL certificate problem'
+ SSL_STATUS='curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate'
```

Having tested this is not the result of the grep but curl, and I do not know why (it still occurred when using `SSL_STATUS=$( curl https://${DOMAIN}` ) which is the basis).

I might just not be understanding how something works here because I'm thick but any assistance would be appreciated.

```
SSL_STATUS=$( curl https://${DOMAIN} 2>&1 | grep "SSL certificate problem" )
```

probably should have mentioned before but setting the function to just run the curl command drops it out of the script too so it's not setting the output to a variable that's causing trouble.

Comment: Do you have a `set -e` somewhere in your script? It will stop your script if any command returns a non-zero exit code (like curl does when there is a certificate problem).

Comment: Thank you so much. A colleague suggested using set -euox pipefail to debug and that was making the whole thing fall over.

So glad I spent hours rewriting the functions cause of that :)

Thanks again dude

Answer (score 0):

set -e was in the main script for debugging:

```
set -euox pipefail
```

Commented out and now it's sorted. Cheers!